# Range of $\cot^{-1}(2x-x^2)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the range of $$f(x)=\cot^{-1}(2x-x^2), f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$

Putting $f(x)=y$, $$y=\cot^{-1}(2x-x^2) \implies \cot(y)=1-(1-x)^2 \implies \cot(y) \le 1, y \in (0,\pi)$$
$$y \in \left[\frac{\pi}{4}, \pi \right)$$ But when I checked this in Wolfram Alpha, the answer shows $$y \in \left(\frac{-\pi}{2}, 0 \right) \cup \left[\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right]$$ My textbook used the method I used and also showed the answer I got.

Comment: Wolfram is not correct if you are restricting yourself to real $x$. The range must a subset of the largest possible range for $\cot^{-1}x$, which is $(0,\pi)$. The other interval falls outside of this range.

Comment: Your answer seems good to me. Wolfram Alpha does crazy things sometimes.